# Find the number of intersection points of these diagonals in the  −gon

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Find the number of intersection points of the diagonals in an  −gon, 
>   knowing that never three diagonals intersect at a point.

[image]

Firstly, I started defining $a_n$ as the number of intersection point of the diagonals such that no three of them intersect at a point, then if I remove one of the diagonals there will be a $a_{n-1}$ number of intersections, and I thought if I put that diagonal back, I would get count the number of new intersections, but that number has the coefficient $(n-1)!$, so I cannot convert such a non homogeneous relation to homogeneous, how can I count this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the number of intersections of diagonals in a convex equilateral polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010591/what-is-the-number-of-intersections-of-diagonals-in-a-convex-equilateral-polygon)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question. The answer is different for an equilateral $n$-gon if $n$ is even since that will have three diagonals intersecting. (In particular, when $n=6$ the answer to this question is $15$, but the answer to the other question is $13$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each quadruple of vertices there are two diagonals joining opposite
points of the four which intersect in the interior. How many quadruples
of vertices are there?

Comment: but how do we know that there is no another 2 diagonal intersecting at the same point ?

Comment: @Leth Huh? Isn't that given in the question, that no more than $2$ diagonals intersect at a point?

Comment: @bof you're right :)

Answer (score 4):

Each intersection point uniquely corresponds to the set of four endpoints of the chords passing through it. Thus the number of intersection points is
$
\binom{n}{4}.
$